# How to update Production/Sandbox back end URL of already defined API in WSO2 API manager through Database update

Tags: wso2, api-manager, wso2-esb

I have defined nearly 100 API in wso2 instance of QA env, I wanted to move same API to Production Environment . For that I need to manually update Production/Sandbox back end url manually through UI which will be very hectic. Is there any ways I can do update in database in any table directly ?

Comment: updating the tables only will not help, because api artifact is created as synapse xml file when publishing the api, it will also have the endpoint details. So better use apimanager rest apis and automate the process

Comment: thanks Jenananthan